# How to create a chromatic aberration for a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

I'm currently developing a web ui

[image]

recently I added a feature to change the overall effects by some range sliders that do it by changing some filter css like hue rotation, grayscale, invert and blur

[image]

now:

doing some screenshots I randomly did this! and it's cool!!!

[image]

I made it just trying to fit the two in photoshop by lowering the opacity of one

previously I wanted to achieve effects like this by using open gl shader language (and I keep want to do it, because you can achieve better effects and more dynamic) but now, doing this in photoshop as I said, I thought of a little solution to just do the chroma aberration

after that all the css is loaded,

```
$( window ).load(function() {
  //chroma aberration
});
```

by an event (or another range slider) I could clone all the html, lower the opacity of the one in front, and move the one in the back

in this way I could achieve an effect like this

do you have some ideas??
do you think it's possible??
do you think I'm right?? or do you think there is a better solution??

here I have some problem I think:

- the cloned copy should not be clickable
- the cloned copy should behave like the original when there is a hover, transition, animation...
- the cloned copy should not expand the box-size of the page, moving itself (maybe using position:absolute and overflow:hidden)

I tryed this way but it doesn't work

```
$( window ).load(function() {
  //Chromatic Aberration
  //clone all the body
  $('body')
    .children()
    .wrap( "<div class='original'></div>" )
    .clone()
    .insertAfter('.original')
    .addClass('cloned')
    .css('-webkit-filter',
         'hue-rotate(180deg)',
         'blur(3px)',
         'grayscale(50%)',
         'invert(5%)')
    .css('position','absolute')
    .css('left','10%')
    .css('z-index','-500');
  //(hue180,blur3,grayscale25,invert5)
  //lower opacity of the original
  $('body.original').css('opacity','0.5');
});
```

Comment: did you try the blur filter?

Comment: the webpage already have 4 range sliders for filters (there is also blur yes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible but a difficult and javascript-heavy task. I would start by making your css rely on javascript-controlled attributes instead of native css attributes:

Instead of:

```
.button:hover {
    /* fancy hover effects */
}
.button:active {
    /* fancy activation effects */
}
```

Switch to

```
.button.hover {  /* Note: no longer using the :hover pseudo-class */
    /* fancy hover effects */
}
.button.active {
    /* fancy activation effects */
}
```

This is a start. It will let you react to DOM actions through custom logic, rather than native CSS. This is necessary because there will be no way to activate native CSS effects on your blurred layer.

Now you need to add and remove these custom `.hover`, `.active` classes manually:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    // Add `.hover` class on hover start
    buttons[i].onmouseover = function(button) {
        this.classList.add('hover');
    }.bind(buttons[i]);

    // Remove `.hover` class on hover end
    buttons[i].onmouseout = function(button) {
        this.classList.remove('hover');
    }.bind(buttons[i]);

    // Add `.active` class on mouse down
    buttons[i].onmousedown = function(button) {
        this.classList.add('active');
    }.bind(buttons[i]);

    // Remove `.active` class on mouse up
    buttons[i].onmouseup = function() {
        this.classList.remove('active');
    }.bind(buttons[i]);
}
```

Ok, that's enough to make your original layer controlled via custom events. But now we need to add the blurred layer. We can implement some custom deep-cloning. We want this to be custom because as we're cloning, we're going to want to be able to take custom actions (adding events).

```
var customCloneNode = function(node) {

    var cloned = node.cloneNode(false); /* DON'T clone children; we'll do it manually */

    // In a moment we'll do some custom logic with `cloned`

    var childNodes = node.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++)
        cloned.appendChild(customCloneNode(childNodes[i]));

    return cloned;

};
```

So we know how to simulate css events, and clone html nodes. Now we need to combine the two, so that the cloned child gains and loses custom css classes whenever the original, corresponding element gains/loses them:

```
var cloneNodeWithLinkedEvents = function(node) {

    var cloned = node.cloneNode(false); /* DON'T clone children */

    // Here's the custom logic:
    node.onmouseover = function(parallelNode) {
        // Add a "hover" class to the original node AND the cloned one!
        this.classList.add('hover');
        parallelNode.classList.add('hover');
    }.bind(node, cloned);

    node.onmouseout = function(parallelNode) {
        this.classList.remove('hover');
        parallelNode.classList.remove('hover');
    }.bind(node, cloned);

    // Note: For brevity I've only added the hover event here.
    // It will be important to add the active event, as well as
    // any value changes in input elements, etc.

    var childNodes = node.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++)
        cloned.appendChild(cloneNodeWithLinkedEvents(childNodes[i]));

    return cloned;

};
```

Now we can make a duplicate element from the original:

```
var originalElem = document.getElementByClassName('ui')[0];
var parallelElem = cloneNodeWithLinkedEvents(originalElem);

// Add the cloned node to the same parent which is holding `originalElem`
originalElem.parentNode.appendChild(parallelElem);

// Give the parallel node a unique class so we can style it:
parallelElem.classList.add('duplicate');
```

Now do the styling for the duplicate element:

```
.ui.duplicate {
    left: -10px;
    top: -5px;
    opacity: 0.3;
    z-index: 2; /* Or whatever value is necessary to make it appear on top */
}
```

Working example:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var cloneNodeWithLinkedEvents = function(node) {
            
      var cloned = node.cloneNode(false); /* DON'T clone children */
      
      if (node.classList && node.classList.contains('button')) {
        
          // Here's the custom logic for buttons:
          node.onmouseover = function(parallelNode) {
              this.classList.add('hover');
              parallelNode.classList.add('hover');
          }.bind(node, cloned);

          node.onmouseout = function(parallelNode) {
              this.classList.remove('hover');
              parallelNode.classList.remove('hover');
          }.bind(node, cloned);
        
      }
      
      if (node.nodeName === 'INPUT') {
          
          var changeFunc = function(parallelNode) {
              parallelNode.value = this.value;
          }.bind(node, cloned);
          node.addEventListener('input', changeFunc);
          node.addEventListener('keyup', changeFunc);
          node.addEventListener('keydown', changeFunc);
          
      }

      // Note: For brevity I've only added the hover event here.
      // It will be important to add the active event, as well as
      // any value changes in input elements, etc.

      var childNodes = node.childNodes;
      for (var i = 0; i < childNodes .length; i++) {
          cloned.appendChild(cloneNodeWithLinkedEvents(childNodes[i]));
      }
      return cloned;

  };

  var originalElem = document.getElementsByClassName('ui')[0];
  var parallelElem = cloneNodeWithLinkedEvents(originalElem);

  originalElem.parentNode.appendChild(parallelElem);
  parallelElem.classList.add('duplicate');
 
 };
```

```css
.ui {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #000000;
}
.ui .button {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px; line-height: 30px;
    margin-left: -51px; margin-top: -16px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: monospace;
    border: 2px dotted #ff0000;
    background-color: #800000;
    color: #ffffff;
    
    transition: background-color 300ms linear;
}
.ui .button.hover {
    background-color: #808080;
}
.ui .button1 { left: 20%; top: 20%; }
.ui .button2 { left: 50%; top: 20%; }
.ui .button3 { left: 80%; top: 20%; }

.ui .decoration {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%; top: 30%;
    width: 40%; height: 5%;
    background-color: #5050ff;
}
.ui .text {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%; top: 38%;
    width: 90%;
    color: #6060df;
}
.ui input {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px; height: 30px; line-height: 30px;
    left: 10%; top: 70%;
    color: #00ff00;
}

.ui {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
}
.ui.duplicate {
    left: -10px; top: -5px;
    pointer-events: none !important;
    opacity: 0.7;
    z-index: 2;
    
    filter: hue-rotate(60deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="ui">
    <div class="button button1">BUTTON1</div>
    <div class="button button2">BUTTON2</div>
    <div class="button button3">BUTTON3</div>
    <div class="decoration"></div>
    <div class="text">
         Some text haha wheeee yayyy<br/>
         Some text haha wheeee yayyy<br/>
         Some text haha wheeee yayyy<br/>
    </div>
    <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

Note that hovering on the duplicated layer doesn't activate any hover effects, and hovering on the original activates effects on both! Also, note that typing into the `input` element links value-change events to the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, it's all very difficult for me that I'm not a programmer (I imagine you got) but I'll try my best to do it

thank you

Comment: Sure, glad I could help! Be aware that this example doesn't account for many technicalities; e.g. if there are any elements with `id` properties set, those will become non-unique (and therefore invalid) after cloning. Also note that there are still a wide range of input actions that haven't been addressed - the working example only demonstrates hover events, and input value changes.